# Populating Data from a Column Multiple Times in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, python, microsoft-office, visual-basic

I currently have a spreadsheet that contains a repeating set of data in specific columns with one field in each row being blank, such as the following:

[image: Table containing Repeating Data]

I also have a column of numbers I wish to have inserted into this table. Each unique value in this column needs to go into the blank column on my table for each set of repeating numbers on my first column.

So if the first column of numbers contained 1234, 5678, 91011 one number per row, repeating down, and I have a new set of data that needs to be inserted in the next blank column with each unique new number being inserted next to a set of the repeating 3 numbers in the original column, is there a way to do this?

It would look something like the following:

[image: Completed Table]

I am repeating this by copy pasting each key into the repeating column repeatedly currently, and was looking for a way to mass enter the data. Is this possible? I would be open to doing this with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use INDEX with COUNTIF to return the correct row:

```
=INDEX($E$2:$E$5,COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2))
```

[image]

Comment: This is the ticket! Thank you!

Comment: @AdamHart if this worked for you please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.